# Bookmark in main menu bar?

Tags: menu

Ubuntu 12.04  I somehow wound up with a bookmark for a web page on my main menu bar (the one at the top of the desktop with "Applications" and "Places")  How can I delete it, or add other bookmarks?

Comment: Please post a screenshot

Comment: @Naveen

http://www.sdsitehosting.com/jnojr/pics/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-08%2010:20:53.png

Answer (score 0):

From the Firefox menu goto `View` > `Tool Bars`  and click on `Bookmarks Toolbar`